When does a short exact sequence of abelian groups with $B\cong A\oplus C$ split?
$\hspace{20pt}$Duplicate on stackexchange.
This question, in a way, extends this one. The question is what are some sufficient conditions on the abelian group $B$ so that if $B\cong A\oplus C$ and a sequence
$$0\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow C\longrightarrow 0$$
is exact, then it splits?
One of the answers to the linked question claims that a sufficient condition is that $B$ is finitely generated. Where can I find some more extensive, or ongoing work on similar results with weaker sufficient conditions on $B$? Also, if you know some other sufficient condition, please tell it in an answer.
Example:
Is $B\leq\mathbb{Q}^n$, for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, a sufficient condition?

Also related, here on MO: Do all exact sequences $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow A \oplus B \rightarrow B \rightarrow 0$ split for finitely generated abelian groups?  In particular, @StevenLandsburg's answer (see also elsewhere) might count as a reference.

Being of finite rank is definitely not enough; the most obvious example of such nonsplit sequence has $B \cong \bigoplus_I \Bbb Z/4 \oplus \bigoplus_I \Bbb Z/2$ for some infinite $I$.

@DenisT I know for that example, but how is the rank of that group finite? Something here is 4, but the rank should be $|I|$.

Well, in my world rank of $A$ denotes the dimension of $A \otimes \Bbb Q$; it's even written in a Wikipedia article you've referenced that bounded torsion abelian groups have rank zero.

@DenisT I see, I understood the definition wrongly. I'll just simplify the example to $B\leq\mathbb{Q}^n$. I am sorry for the confusion.
